# Calendar Activity implementation. How to reload calendar view? Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, calendar

I am currently developing an android app that has a Calendar as one of its activities. My calendar works just fine but I have the following problem:

For every month I have to make a request for events to an API (I am using AsyncHttpClient to achieve this), so every time the user clicks the button to see the next or previous month, I make a new request, get the data asynchronously and save it into the database. What I'm doing right know is starting a new intent for every new request, but that is just wrong because every time I click to see a different month, if I click the back button I have a bunch of instances of the same activity but with the previous months I just saw.

What I really want to do is to "refresh" the CalendarActivity with the new data I just got from the request, but I'm not really sure how to do this. I tried adding the flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK to the flags on my intent but it doesn't do what I expect. I also try to put a ProgressDialog and wait until the request is done but the problem is I still do the statActivity after the request is made, but I don't know how else I can do this.

Here is some of my code, particularly the one I have after the request is done and it was successful:

**AsyncHttpClientManager.java**

```
public static void getCalendar(final int year, final int month,
        final Context context, final Context appContext,
        final ProgressDialog prgDialog) {
    prgDialog.show();
    cookieStore = new PersistentCookieStore(appContext);

    // Change the default timeout from 10secs to 30secs
    // Calendar takes time to load
    client.setTimeout(DEFAULT_TIMEOUT);

    client.setCookieStore(cookieStore);
    client.addHeader("Accept", HEADER);

    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    String[] dates = getDate(year, month);

    Log.d(TAG, "start: " + dates[0] + " end: " + dates[1]);
    params.put("start_date", dates[0]);
    params.put("end_date", dates[1]);

    client.get(getAbsoluteUrl(CALENDAR_PATH), params,
            new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int statusCode,
                        org.apache.http.Header[] headers,
                        java.lang.String responseString,
                        java.lang.Throwable throwable) {
                    prgDialog.hide();
                    .....
                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers,
                        JSONObject response) {

                    if (statusCode == 200) {
                        prgDialog.hide();
                        Gson gson = new Gson();
                        Calendar calendar = gson.fromJson(
                                response.toString(), Calendar.class);
                        CalendarController.getInstance(context);
                        CalendarController.insertCalendar(calendar);

                        Intent intentC = new Intent(context,
                                CalendarActivity.class);

                        java.util.Calendar current = java.util.Calendar
                                .getInstance();
                        if (current.get(java.util.Calendar.MONTH) + 1 == month
                                && current.get(java.util.Calendar.YEAR) == year) {
                            intentC.putExtra("first_time", true);
                        } else {
                            intentC.putExtra("first_time", false);
                            intentC.putExtra("month", month);
                            intentC.putExtra("year", year);
                        }
                        context.startActivity(intentC);
                    }
                }

            });
}
```

Here is the onClick() method when clicking the button to see the next or previous month:

**CalendarActivity.java**

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == prevMonth) {
        if (month <= 1) {
            month = 12;
            year--;
        } else {
            month--;
        }
        AsyncHttpClientManager.getCalendar(year, month, this,
                getApplicationContext(), prgDialog);
        setGridCellAdapterToDate(month, year);
    }
    if (v == nextMonth) {
        if (month > 11) {
            month = 1;
            year++;
        } else {
            month++;
        }
        prgDialog.show();
        AsyncHttpClientManager.getCalendar(year, month, this,
                getApplicationContext(), prgDialog);
        setGridCellAdapterToDate(month, year);
    }

}
```

I also tried to finish CalendarActivity before making the request, but the request takes some time so the current CalendarActivity finishes, gets me back to the previous activity and a few seconds later the new instance of CalendarActivity gets launched.

Hope anyone can help me with this. Thanks in advance.